# How to get timestamp like this : 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000 in php

Tags: php, datetime, time

How to output the current time like this `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000` in php?

I tried everything W3Schools [PHP Date Time page](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_date.asp) had, but didn't get the above format.

Comment: Reading the actual [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date) is more helpful than w3schools.

Comment: The suggested answer to this question does not mention the PHP `DateTime` class. You can resolve the wanted result with a one liner: `$date = (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u);`. So the answer to this question is not complete, because it does not mention the `DateTime` class.